# Strange Java error- float getting set to Infinity

Tags: java, processing

I'm new to Java, and I'm using Processing to make some data visualizations. I'm getting this strange error in my code though, was wondering if anyone could help me out. It seems the Xspacing float keeps getting set to Infinity, however when I print out the expression it gets set to the proper value gets printed...

```
  float Xspacing = (endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values;  
  println((endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values);  
  println(Xspacing);
```

Result is:

49.0
Infinity

Any help would be appreciated!

Sorry, I wrote this out very quickly and omitted some pretty necessary info:

49.0 IS what is should be. All other types are floats, besides values which is an integer.
The code DOES compile, and println is build into Processing, which is the framework (correct term?) that I'm using. It is basically a function that prints to the console in the Processing GUI.

Xspacing was intended to be data for my class "Graph," however when I define the variable within a public function "drawBasic" everything works fine. Now I am just curious....

Using System.out.println(0 yields the same results. Initial values or variables are:

float startX = 120.00001
float endX = 740.0
int values = 12
width is an integer (although not explicit) that is set to 800

The odd thing seems to be that within a function definition this works fine, its only when I try to define it within the class that it doesn't work...

Comment: Try placing in a `double`.  Are any intermediate steps in the calculation resulting in very large numbers?

Comment: So 49.0 is definitely the correct value? Would be good if your question included the values of endX, width, startX and values, just so people could validate the outcome.

Comment: And adding to @antsyawn's request, having their exact types would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Dan: Could you please also add in the values of the inputs to your formula?  Also, since the `println` is non-standard, could you try the `System.out.println` version and see what it outputs in the two cases?

Comment: @Dan: if the code works in a public function but not within your class, are you sure there is not something like variable shadowing happening, or some other thread modifying your inputs?  Can you try printing out the values immediately before the computation that is failing (if you haven't already)?

Comment: @Dan: What do you mean by "defining it in a class?"  Are you trying to make it a field that is initialized outside a method?  If so, are you sure all of the inputs are initialized first?

Comment: My hypothesis is correct- the problem is with the values variable. Its also class data, and for some reason when I replace "values" with the literal 12 it works fine outside of any function...

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to Java and OOP in general- Ive spent the last year in C. What was I doing wrong that it wouldn't take the values variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your code couldn't be like that because a number *.04 creates a double, and that would mean you'd need to cast the expression into a float.

For your code to compile it would have to be something like

```
float Xspacing = (float)((endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values);  
println((endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values);  
println(Xspacing);
```

Now, on the result. If your code had, for example:

```
    System.out.println(3/0);
```

Java would give you a java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

However, if you have

```
    System.out.println(3f/0);
```

Then Java will give you "Infinity". Why? http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float Xspacing = (endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values;  
println((float)((endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values));  
println(Xspacing);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float Xspacing = (endX-(width*.04) - startX)/ values;
```

Even assuming the variables are floats that line does not compile, because of the 0.4 double literal.

Also 'println' is not a standalone method, so you must have written your own.

What is your *actual* code?

Answer (score -1):

you forget a `)` and you should've `put System.out.println(xspacing);`

fyi you can also just type `syso` and `ctrl spacebar` and it will print out the print statement for you.